# Salesforce Apex Incorrect Month Name

Tags: apex

I am trying to get the Month Name from a Date using Apex
I assumed I could use the following:

sDateTime = 2024-04-01 00:00:00
string sMonth = sDateTime.format('MMMM');

Assumed I would get April.
But instead I get March

If I update startDateTime = 2024-04-02 00:00:00
I get April

It seems it does this for any value where its the first of the month.
Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: Given it's the first of the month, I suspect it will probably be due to timezone issues. I wonder if you might want to try looking at how the locale settings of the running user impact this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the fun world of Datetimes!

This is a classic example of you thinking you're giving Salesforce a datetime in your local timezone, but Salesforce thinking that the datetime is GMT (i.e. UTC +0).

When you use `.format()`, Salesforce is saying "A ha! This Datetime is GMT but the running user is not. So we'll adjust the Datetime for them!". For me, here in UTC -6 land, that'd cause `2024-04-01 00:00:00` to become `2024-03-31 18:00:00`. And that there is how you're getting "March" instead of "April".

This is an issue for anyone in a UTC -X time zone (i.e. most of Greenland, the Americas, Caribbean, and a decent swath of Polynesia)

The root of the issue here is in how you're creating your Datetime instance, but I can't really be more specific than that without seeing your actual code. I'll have to come back to this tomorrow to add some examples of things that cause this timezone discrepancy to happen, but one that I'm pretty sure of is assigning a Date instance to a Datetime variable.

Quick example to demonstrate

```java
Date d = Date.today();
// Assigning a date to a datetime is one surefire way to get into a situation
//   where Salesforce incorrectly assumes the timezone 
Datetime dt = d;
system.debug(d); // prints 2024-01-10 at time of writing
system.debug(dt.format('YYYY-MM-dd')); // prints 2024-01-09 at time of writing
```

In the above example, using `.formatGMT()` would return the correct result.
The better solution though would be to use `Datetime.newInstance()` to pass in a date and time (which ends up making Salesforce think the Datetime is in the executing user's timezone)

```java
Date d = Date.today();
// Using newInstance() keeps the resulting datetime in the executing
//   user's timezone (instead of always being GMT)
Datetime dt = Datetime.newInstance(d, Time.newInstance(0, 0, 0, 0));
system.debug(d); // prints 2024-01-10 at time of writing
system.debug(dt.format('YYYY-MM-dd')); // also prints 2024-01-10 at time of writing
```

Comment: Turns out my "other examples" didn't cover much additional ground. Just messing around with Datetime's `newInstance()` and `newInstanceGmt()`. The takeaway: just avoid putting a `Date` into a `Datetime` (or casting it to a `Datetime`).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and example